# “iCloud storage not enough for backup” message in spite of having loads of space

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I have an iPhone 11 Pro and a 2Tb iCloud family membership. I have utilised ~450 Gb i.e. I’ve got more than enough storage for backing up my iPhone.

In spite of this, I get the aforementioned message...

Any solution to this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing when you get this message?  You indicated you've used 450gb, is that only from you or the combined amount from everyone?  Is anyone else in the family getting the same error?  What have you done to resolve this problem yourself?

Comment: 450gigs is combined amount. Nobody else is getting this error. Tried finding solutions on the net for it, but couldn’t get anything.

Comment: Is this iPhone the only device signed in with the same Apple ID?  How much do you need for your next backup (according to iCloud)?